# What is causing this bcdboot error in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, bootsector

I was doing the instructions at https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/239203/7125

When after doing "bcdboot e:\windows /v /s e:" I get this error:

```
BFSVC Error: SetNamedSecurityInfo failed! Error code = 0x5
BFSVC Error: No process found using \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolume5\EFI\Microsoft\Boot file.
BFSVC Error: BfspSetSecurityDescriptor(\\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolume5\EFI\Microsoft\Boot) failed! Last Error = 0x5
```

There's some other text around the error, but this seems to be the important part.

The external HDD is in a SATA USB 3 enclosure, if that matters. I'm executing bcdboot from a functioning Win 10 installation in a VM, with the external HDD connected as E:

Answer (score 0):

When running `cmd` to enter the command in question, I just had to right click "Run as Administrator" in the Start Menu, and it worked.